# ADOMD.Net Net 6 authentication issues

Tags: c#, .net-core, powerbi, azure-analysis-services, adomd

I'm trying to migrate an application from Net 4.x to Net 6 and I've stumbled about a weird situation.
Basically I want to switch **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64** to **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64** which from what I've seen is supposed to be used with Net 6.

The error in question:

**MsalServiceException: AADSTS50052: The password entered exceeds the maximum length. Please reach out to your admin to reset the password.**

I'm using **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64** in my Net 4.x which has a dependency on Microsoft.Identity.Client.
The application calls power BI with a connection string that has Password={accessToken} which is my OnBehalfToken.
On version 4.10, the connection works fine but If I upgrade the package to the latest version I now get the error that the password is too long. From what I've gathered the issue starts occurring after version 4.43.

The same behaviour is also in net core equivalent package **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64** which as far as I can tell should be pretty much exactly the same. This particular package must have Microsoft.Identity.Client (=> 4.43.0)

The code kinda looks like this

```
        string ConnectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={server};User ID=;Password={accessToken};Catalog={databaseName};Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate";

        using (AdomdConnection adomdConnection = new AdomdConnection())
        {
            adomdConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand();
            adomdCommand.Connection = adomdConnection;                
            adomdCommand.CommandText = "SAMPLE QUERY";
            adomdConnection.Open(); // Fails AADSTS50052
            CellSet cellSet = adomdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();
            adomdConnection.Close();
        }
```

I don't understand why it's working on the older versions but won't on the latest version in 4.x or any version in Net 6.

Is there another way to accomplish this, or am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Comment: And how long is the Access Token?

Comment: It's 2184 characters, but that wasn't an issue on the previous version.

Comment: After further investigation it would seem this issue is happening only on the lastest version,as of writing this which are 19.65.4 for both NET and NetCore.